# All links open in Browser, how to stop it?

Tags: applications, 5.1-lollipop

So I got a rather new (but cheap)  Y100 Plus from Dogee with Android 5.1 and ALL Links open to the browser.
Even when someone sends me a Location, it opens Google Maps in Browser instead of the App.

I was NEVER prompted with what app to open any link, which is pretty weird, and probably the cause of my problems.
That also means that resetting the preferences on my Browser doesnt do anything (tried that).
More annoying, "Open Link With" which would have been my workaround doesnt hep, because my browser doesnt give me the share option.

Comment: Go to settings>apps and find that browser and just clear defaults for that app, next time it will prompt to choose app to open link

Comment: @Једноруки Крстивоје: FFS, THAT IS MY PROBLEM: THAT DOESNT DO ANYTHING. I WAS NEEEEEEVER PROMPTED WHAT APP FOR THE ENTIRE TIME I HAD THAT PHONE (and I bought it brand new).

I NEVER SET ANY PREFERENCE!

Comment: Did you go to settings>apps>browser > open by default and then tap on clear defaults?

Comment: Yes I did. Again: that is my problem: There are no defaults to clear (i still clicked on it).

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a single app for browsing installed on your phone, then all links will have to be opened in it, if the app from which you are clicking the link doesnt provide in-app webview, to open links.

Comment: Its not about browsing.
Its about all the other app-related links like a Location (Google Maps link) Youtube Videos and so on.
I dont care about in-app web view